# How to persist variable from remote shell

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access

I am doing ssh on a machine and executing certain commands.

My last command gives me a variable which I need for a script present locally. However, how do I access that variable after I logout from the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer the string variable=value in a file using scp to get it from your remote environment:

```
$ cat file.txt
X=10
```

Then use "eval" to load the variable in your local environment.

```
VAR=$(cat file.txt)                                                              
eval $VAR                                                                        
echo $X
10
```

Hope to be helpful! :)

Comment: Or in one line without the temporary file: `eval $(ssh "$host" "my_command")` (assuming that you have full control over the host, and that you don't have extraneous output to get rid of).